# Find Duplicates limited to multiple ranges - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose our problem can be simplified like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['C_rows'] = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C2', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C1']
df['values'] = ['customer1', 4321, 1266, 5671, 'customer2', 123, 7344,'customer3', 4321, 4444, 5674, 'customer4']
```

with the table:

```
    C_rows  values
0   C1      customer1
1   C2      4321
2   C3      1266
3   C2      5671
4   C1      customer2
5   C2      123
6   C3      7344
7   C1      customer3
8   C2      4321
9   C3      4444
10  C4      5674
11  C1      customer4
```

How can we vectorise finding duplicate `C_rows` between each `C1`,
i.e.  `row3` has duplicate `C2` occurring in rows 1 and 3.
The dataset I am working with has 50,000 rows, and between each `C1` is about 15 rows.

e.g. check duplicates like this:

```
    C_rows  values
0   C1      customer1
1   C2      4321
2   C3      1266
3   C2      5671
```

*C2 is duplicate*

```
4   C1      customer2
5   C2      123
6   C3      7344
```

*No duplicates*

```
7   C1      customer3
8   C2      4321
9   C3      4444
10  C4      5674
```

*No duplicates*

without using for loops - and quick (vectorised).

Comment: In your actual data, what do the values in C_rows look like?

Comment: around 100 cells across, with different properties

Comment: Do you want to get rid of all C2? Or keep the first?

Comment: I just want to identify them, most likely will then keep first (need to analyse my dataset first)

Comment: Does the C_rows column groups always start from `C1` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For very fast vectorized solution create new clumn by consecutive values between `C1` and then check [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df['dupe'] = df.assign(dupe=df['C_rows'].eq('C1').cumsum()).duplicated(['C_rows','dupe'])
print (df)
   C_rows     values   dupe
0      C1  customer1  False
1      C2       4321  False
2      C3       1266  False
3      C2       5671   True
4      C1  customer2  False
5      C2        123  False
6      C3       7344  False
7      C1  customer3  False
8      C2       4321  False
9      C3       4444  False
10     C4       5674  False
11     C1  customer4  False
```

And if need filter:

```
df = df[df.assign(dupe=df['C_rows'].eq('C1').cumsum()).duplicated(['C_rows','dupe'])]
print (df)
  C_rows values
3     C2   5671
```

If want check duplicates groups:

```
df = df.assign(dupe=df['C_rows'].eq('C1').cumsum())
a = df.loc[df.duplicated(['C_rows','dupe']), 'dupe']
df['dupe'] = df['dupe'].isin(a)
print (df)
   C_rows     values   dupe
0      C1  customer1   True
1      C2       4321   True
2      C3       1266   True
3      C2       5671   True
4      C1  customer2  False
5      C2        123  False
6      C3       7344  False
7      C1  customer3  False
8      C2       4321  False
9      C3       4444  False
10     C4       5674  False
11     C1  customer4  False
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like `groupby` + `apply` (with `duplicated`) would do it.

```
df.groupby(df.C_rows.eq('C1').cumsum()).C_rows.apply(pd.Series.duplicated)

0     False
1     False
2     False
3      True
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
Name: C_rows, dtype: bool
```

Use the mask to filter out `df`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use transform and duplicated i.e

```
df['g'] = df['values'].astype(str).str.contains('[A-z]').cumsum()
df['is_dup'] = df.groupby('g')['C_rows'].transform(lambda x : x.duplicated().any())

  C_rows     values  g  is_dup
0      C1  customer1  1    True
1      C2       4321  1    True
2      C3       1266  1    True
3      C2       5671  1    True
4      C1  customer2  2   False
5      C2        123  2   False
6      C3       7344  2   False
7      C1  customer3  3   False
8      C2       4321  3   False
9      C3       4444  3   False
10     C4       5674  3   False
11     C1  customer4  4   False
```

In case you want to find only duplicated rows then remove the `any()`

```
df['is_dup'] = df.groupby('g')['C_rows'].transform(lambda x : x.duplicated())
```

Comment: nice one, only I think `groupby` here id should be slowier.

Comment: I thought groups were from values. Didn't think group always starts from `C1`

Comment: For my example, groups started with `C1`, but thanks