# Pandas: Remove limited duplicates

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

So, I have a file that gets generated at runtime. A sample of the file looks like this:

```
ID,Class_id,Column_A,Column_B,Column_C,Column_D,Mask
1,987,vermont,CA,450,liase,2
2,456,WB,cloo,452,var,1
3,987,CA,Cp,1000000,liase,2
4,456,SA,Cap,98376,clop,1
5,765,IN,clas,543,king,2
6,987,SA,CLA,200,loop,2
7,456,BEG,loop,876,var,1
```

As you can see, duplicate elements for `Class_id` are present. Also `Mask` specifies the maximum number of duplicate elements that can be present in the file.

What I'm trying to do is to remove the last occurence of the duplicate element one by one until the number of duplicate records is same as the its `Mask` value.

In case of above file,

987 of `Class_id` is occuring 3 times. Its `Mask` value is 2. So it can occur, at maximum, 2 times only. So i need to remove the last occurence of 987 which is the 6th record. The order of the records in the file is irrelevant here.

The output I'm trying to get at is like this:

```
ID,Class_id,Column_A,Column_B,Column_C,Column_D,Mask
1,987,vermont,CA,450,liase,2
3,987,CA,Cp,1000000,liase,2
2,456,WB,cloo,452,var,5
5,765,IN,clas,543,king,2
```

I scoured through this site, and yet couldn't get a viable solution. These are the sites I referenced;

[Pandas: remove reverse duplicates from dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474799/pandas-remove-reverse-duplicates-from-dataframe?rq=1)
[Find Duplicates limited to multiple ranges - pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48338971/find-duplicates-limited-to-multiple-ranges-pandas)
[python pandas remove duplicate columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984119/python-pandas-remove-duplicate-columns/32961145)
[How to conditionally remove duplicates from a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45907133/how-to-conditionally-remove-duplicates-from-a-pandas-dataframe)
[Drop all duplicate rows in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-in-python-pandas)

I noticed that Python has a `drop_duplicates` function. Nut how can i limit the number of duplicates to remove?

Could somebody help out a newbie here please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with mask comparing `Series` by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with column `Mask` and [`lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.lt.html) (`<`):

```
df = df[df.groupby('Class_id').cumcount().lt(df.Mask)]
print (df)

   ID  Class_id Column_A Column_B  Column_C Column_D  Mask
0   1       987  vermont       CA       450    liase     2
1   2       456       WB     cloo       452      var     1
2   3       987       CA       Cp   1000000    liase     2
4   5       765       IN     clas       543     king     2
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby('Class_id').cumcount())
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    0
5    2
6    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `cumcount` to address trimming excess rows off.  Use `pd.factorize` + `np.bincount` to filter out rows with fewer rows than `Mask`

```
mask = df.Mask.values
f, u = pd.factorize(df.Class_id.values)

cond1 = df.groupby('Class_id').cumcount().lt(mask)
cond2 = np.bincount(f)[f] >= mask

df[cond1 & cond2]

   ID  Class_id Column_A Column_B  Column_C Column_D  Mask
0   1       987  vermont       CA       450    liase     2
1   2       456       WB     cloo       452      var     1
2   3       987       CA       Cp   1000000    liase     2
```

You'll notice that this is **NOT** what OP has as their desired output.  That output is not consistent with number of rows being **EQUAL** to the value in the `Mask` column.

---

Another way using `transform('size')` instead of `pd.factorize` to eliminate rows whose count is too small.

```
g = df.groupby('Class_id')

mask = df.Mask.values
cond1 = g.cumcount().lt(mask)
cond2 = g.ID.transform('size').ge(mask)

df[cond1 & cond2]

   ID  Class_id Column_A Column_B  Column_C Column_D  Mask
0   1       987  vermont       CA       450    liase     2
1   2       456       WB     cloo       452      var     1
2   3       987       CA       Cp   1000000    liase     2
```

Comment: Just commented.

Comment: I am confused, something missing?

Comment: Based on OP's words "until the number of duplicate records is same as the its Mask value" There intention is ambiguous.  I'm making an assumption that they meant for the number of elements of `'Class_id'` to be equal to the value in the `Mask` column.  It may be that what you have is exactly what they wanted and is what I did in the first place.  But I noticed this and want to address it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cumcount`

```
In [260]: df[df.groupby('Class_id').cumcount() < df['Mask']]
Out[260]:
   ID  Class_id Column_A Column_B  Column_C Column_D  Mask
0   1       987  vermont       CA       450    liase     2
1   2       456       WB     cloo       452      var     1
2   3       987       CA       Cp   1000000    liase     2
4   5       765       IN     clas       543     king     2
```